# Flutter - How do you detect when an already down pointer enters widget's area?

Tags: flutter, listener, gesture

How do you detect when an already pointer enters a widget (i.e. after having already been down outside the widget then enters the widget)?

This is for flutter mobile app, not web.  The Listener onPointerEnter seems to have been the way to do this in this past, but that has been deprecated in favor of MouseRegion.enter, which only works for web.